# Case insensitive unique constraint for Postgres + EF Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using Postgres + EF Core. I have a column called Name which I want to be unique. I have tried the following:

```
builder.HasIndex(s => s.Name).IsUnique();
```

but this allows "test123" and "TEST123" to be accepted. How can I add a case insensitive unique constraint with fluent api?

Or do I just need to create a NormalizedName column and add the unique constraint to that. Seems like a lot of work every time I want to add a unique constraint to a column.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using EF Core 5.0, then see below (probably the better solution). Otherwise, I added a case insensitive check by making use of the `citext` extension as described [here](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/misc/collations-and-case-sensitivity.html#the-citext-type). There are some limitations, I won't list them here but you can read up on them in the previous link or directly on the [PostgreSQL Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/citext.html).

Also ensure you have the `postgres-contrib` package installed to make use of this extension.

First, enable the extension by adding it to your model builder

```cs
modelBuilder.HasPostgresExtension("citext");
```

Then use the `citext` as the column type

```cs
builder.Property(s => s.Name)
       .HasColumnType("citext")
```

#### EF Core 5.0

With EF Core 5.0 there's better support by making use of [Collations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity). You can also check out the [Npgsql docs](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/misc/collations-and-case-sensitivity.html) in regards to PostrgeSQL. This gets over a bunch of limitations with `citext` above and gives you a lot more control.

So the (untested) steps are:

1. Create a collation as a database object using ICU. This will create a non-deterministic, case-insensitive ICU collation. If you need something else, check out the [ICU docs](http://userguide.icu-project.org/collation).

```cs
modelBuilder.HasCollation("case_insensitive_collation", locale: "en-u-ks-primary", provider: "icu", deterministic: false);
```

2. Now on you column, you can add:

```cs
builder.HasIndex(s => s.Name)
       .UseCollation("case_insensitive_collation")
       .IsUnique();
```

If you achieved it some other way, I'd love to hear how.

Comment: Use the preview release of npgsql (current latest is 5.0.0-rc1) and then yes you can.

Comment: Thanks, if you have two case insensitive columns, and they need to be unique together. Is it better to make them case insensitive using Property and then add a unique index, or add a unique index with collation like you did? If you use an index will the columns still use the collation outside of that index?

Comment: Great question, and I'm not sure if the collation is kind of "inherited" as such. Maybe you could test it out. But I think I would probably try create an index over the columns `.HasIndex(p => new {p.FirstColumn , p.SecondColumn})` and then chain on the `UseCollation` to that. At least then it's clearer more on the intention that the index should be unique I think?

Comment: The EF Core 5.0 version worked great for me, thank you!